# Simple GLUT library issue

Tags: c++, glut

This will be my first post on stackoverflow.
So, I'm making a simple program(VISUAL STUDIO 2012), using GLUT library. I basically try to display a torus, but instead I get a black screen.

```
#include<gl/glut.h>
#include<math.h>

GLfloat r=8;
GLint spin=0;
GLfloat light_position[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
GLfloat ex,ey=0, ez, upx=0, upy=0, upz=0;

void init(){
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void display(void){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPushMatrix();
double sine = (float)sin((float)spin);
double cosine =  (float)cos((float)spin);
ex=r*sine;
ez=r*cosine;
gluLookAt(ex,ey,-5.0,0,0,0,upx,upy,upz);
glColor3b(1.0,0,0);
glutSolidTorus(0.275,0.85,8,15);
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(40.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0,20.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
switch(button)
{
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if( state == GLUT_DOWN){
        spin = (spin+15)%360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
    break;
default:
    break;

    }
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
glutInitWindowPosition(300,300);
glutCreateWindow("Light Rotating Torus");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Can somebody modify it/give a hint, so it displays something?
Thanks

Comment: I can't see you adding any lights except in `reshape`.

Comment: Also the `lookAt` code looks strange. You're computing `ez` but then you're using `ey` instead.

Comment: Also, try learning [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for example instead of glut. glut is extremely old and basically sucks ;) (but that doesn't have anything to do with your problem).

Comment: Also note that lighting a torus from its center won't look good.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the camera always in the torus plane, seeing only the outer side (which is in total darkness)?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is your UP vector. You set `upx`, `upy` and `upz`. That is not a valid up vector, try changing `upy` to `1.0f`. Because of this, your torus was probably rendered out of screen.

Also, glClear doesn't take GL_DEPTH_TEST as a parameter.
Correct call should be:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Because of this, your screen was not cleared and stayed black (while you set glClearColor to be white).

And lastly, main function should *always* return int, never void (though it doesn't change anything in your case)